# Nonparametric MANOVA with nested problem

Tags: r, nested-models

I would like to find out if my dependent variable Y which is a measure of the similarity of two shapes to each other and has no normal distribution, is dependent on factors A, B and C. To do this, 4 people outlined 50 shapes based on 50 different images 6 times each. Hence, I obtained 300 shapes from one person. Each of the 50 different images is characterized by factors A (5 categories), B (3 categories) and C (3 categories). In each of the A categories there are 10 images and inside each category there is at least one image with each of the B and C categories.

I assume that individuals are indistinguishable from each other, so getting the Y measure required comparing each obtained shape with all others (6*4) for 1 of the 50 images. And so, of course, for all images. The measure is symmetric, so it doesn't matter whether we compare shape 1 with 2 or shape 2 with 1. Consequently, I obtain 276 values of measure Y for one image, which I treat as repeated measurements.

As I understand, I have a nested data problem and to get an answer to my question I should use multivariate analysis such as nonparametric MANOVA (MANOVA.RM package in R) -> `MANOVA(Y ~ A + B:A + C:B:A, ...)`.

Is my reasoning correct?